# Kill Scheduler process on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, scheduled-tasks, scheduler, heroku-toolbelt

I have one Heroku process running as follows:

```
=== scheduler (Standard-2X): bundle exec rake keenio:fetch_stats (1)
scheduler.1982: up 2018/09/14 05:31:44 +0530 (~ 12h ago)
```

I need to kill this scheduler, Can I use following command for the same.

```
heroku ps:stop scheduler.1982
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct. See https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#stopping-one-off-dynos for more details.